# In C++, how can I cout a logo that features many special characters?

Tags: c++, escaping, cout

I have a logo that features many special characters, such as escape characters, and I want to print it to the terminal. How should I do this without the compiler throwing "unknown escape sequence" errors?

Here is some example code (that features only one problematic character -- not, say, hundreds):

```
void print_logo();

int main(){
    print_logo();
    return 0;
}

void print_logo(){
    std::cout << "\_ hello _/\n";
}
```

Note that manually escaping all of the special characters in the logo is not an option.

Comment: You may use a [c++ raw string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about raw literals?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const char* tree = R"===(
      *             ,
                       _/^\_
                      <     >
     *                 /.-.\         *
              *        `/&\`                   *
                      ,@.*;@,
                     /_o.I %_\    *
        *           (`'--:o(_@;
                   /`;--.,__ `')             *
                  ;@`o % O,*`'`&\
            *    (`'--)_@ ;o %'()\      *
                 /`;--._`''--._O'@;
                /&*,()~o`;-.,_ `""`)
     *          /`,@ ;+& () o*`;-';\
               (`""--.,_0 +% @' &()\
               /-.,_    ``''--....-'`)  *
          *    /@%;o`:;'--,.__   __.'\
              ;*,&(); @ % &^;~`"`o;@();         *
              /(); o^~; & ().o@*&`;&%O\
        jgs   `"="==""==,,,.,="=="==="`
           __.----.(\-''#####---...___...-----._
         '`         \)_`"""""`
                 .--' ')
               o(  )_-\
                 `"""` `
    )===";
    std::cout << tree;
};
```

Comment: You need to provide a different enclosing sequence than `()`, e.g. `out()out` since there are `)` characters used in the ASCII art.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I certainly agree with your point but somehow it works on MSVC and gcc. Strange.

Comment: from c++11 onwards though

Comment: @odedsh, sure thing but in 2015 C++11 should be implied on every answer without telling otherwise.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Thank you for your suggestion. It helped me to understand the opening and closing sequences.

Answer (score 1):

Add a backslash `\` to every slash :

```
void print_logo(){
    std::cout << "\\_ hello _\/\n";
}
```

Output:

```
\_ hello _/




Press any key to continue
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. In my case, as mentioned in the question, escaping every special character is not an option both because there are hundreds of them and because it makes the logo very difficult to edit by a human.